# Loading Data using ajax not displaying loading div using show/ hide or block/none working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

For the below function I am trying to show a loading screen while ajax request retrieves the records from database. But some how neither jquery show() and hide() function nor javascript element.style.display="Block" working.

```
 function AdvanceSearch()
{
    document.getElementById('divloading').style.display = "Block";
    var _Pets = 0;
    var _WantPets = 0;
    try {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/CommonServices/MatchMe_DetailsAdvanceSearch',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                Pets: _Pets,
                WantPets: _WantPets,    
            },

            success: function (data)
            {

                $('#ListOfWhoMatchesMyProfile').html("");
                $('#MatchMePagination').html("");
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                _responseData = response.Records;
// html string is creating using the records.
                  $('#divloading').delay(2000).hide(20000);

            },

            error: function (ex) {
                document.getElementById('divloading').style.display = "None";
                alert('Failed to Retrieve List of Profile matched with your preferences .' + ex.Text);
               // $('#divloading').show();
            }
        });




    } catch (e)
    {
        alert(e.message);
        document.getElementById('divloading').style.display = "None";
        //$('#divloading').show();
    }

}
```

I did tries using async: false too. But this also didn't solved my problem.

Comment: you should have your .show() happen in the beforeSend: and your .hide() in the complete: functions

Comment: Also your ajax call is not async, which makes the screen freeze until the request is complete.  It never shows because the thread is stopped, until the ajax call is complete, but then is hidden right away again

Answer (score 1):

Do this.  First get rid of the try catch.  Second set the method back to be async.  Disabling async will freeze the screen until the request is complete.  Probably why you never see anything.  It is hidden again by the time you continue the thread.  Third set your show() and hide() in the berforeSend and complete handlers

```
var _Pets = 0;
var _WantPets = 0;
try {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/CommonServices/MatchMe_DetailsAdvanceSearch',
        dataType: 'json',

        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            Pets: _Pets,
            WantPets: _WantPets,    
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            document.getElementById('divloading').style.display = "Block";
        },
        complete: function(){
            document.getElementById('divloading').style.display = "None";
        },
        success: function (data)
        {

            $('#ListOfWhoMatchesMyProfile').html("");
            $('#MatchMePagination').html("");
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            _responseData = response.Records;

        },

        error: function (ex) {
            document.getElementById('divloading').style.display = "None";
            alert('Failed to Retrieve List of Profile matched with your preferences .' + ex.Text);
           // $('#divloading').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks JSON, setting async: true made the code run as expected.

Comment: I am happy I could help

Answer (score 0):

try delaying **try catch** block using 'timeout()'

Comment: Ideally Loading div should be in show() state as soon the function is called, and hide() function would be called on success (ie. once the data has been fetched.)